# Limits of functions with two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How to show that the limit of these two functions is zero when $x \rightarrow 0,y \rightarrow 0$?

1) $(x+y)\ln(x^2+y^2)$

2) ${(x-y)^3 \over x^2+y^2}$

In the first case, I tried to use this inequality $1-{1 \over y}\le \ln(y) \le y-1$. I have managed to show that the limit of the right-hand side is zero in my example:

$\le (x+y)\ln(x^2+y^2) \le (|x|+|y|)(x^2+y^2-1)=|x|^3+|x|^2|y|+|x||y|^2+|y|^3-|x|-|y| \rightarrow 0$

But I have problems with the left-hand side.

And what can I do with my second example?

Comment: If $x,y$ near zero, for the logarithm, then you may get some negative signs that need to be dealt with carefully. The polar trick is the way to go, but it might be worthwhile to understand an argument directly in rectangular coords too. @peterszilas solution below is nice for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first you can handle easily with polar coordinates, the second one using AM-GM:

- $x=r\cos t, y =r \sin t \Rightarrow $
  $$\left|(x+y)\log(x^2+y^2) \right|=r|\cos t+\sin t||\log r^2| \leq 4|r\log r| \stackrel{r \to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$
- $2|x||y| \leq x^2+y^2 \Rightarrow$

$$\left|{(x-y)^3 \over x^2+y^2}\right|\leq |x-y|\left|\frac{x^2+y^2 + 2|x||y|}{x^2+y^2}\right|$$ $$ \leq |x-y| \frac{x^2+y^2+x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=2|x-y|\stackrel{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 1):

$|(x+y)\log (x^2+y^2)| \le$

$(|x|+|y|)|\log (x^2+y^2)| \le$

$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|\log (x^2+y^2)|;$

Set $r:=x^2+y^2$, and consider

$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} 2r^{1/2}| \log r|$.

Hence?

Note :$ |x| =\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, similarly for $y$.

Appended:

Set $r=e^{-z}$ and consider $z \rightarrow \infty$.

Then the expression becomes:

$2\dfrac{|-z|}{e^{z/2}}= 4(\dfrac{z/2}{e^{z/2}})$.

Recall:

$e^{z/2}= 1+ z/2 +(1/2)(z/2)^2....> (1/2)(z/2)^2$

Finally:

$4\dfrac{z/2}{e^{x/2}} <  (4)(2)\dfrac{z/2}{(z/2)^2}= 16\dfrac{1}{z}.$

Take the limit $z \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. But, to find a limit of your expression, I have to use de l'Hospital's rule. Can I simply calculate a derivative of $|logr|$ and then place an answer in absolute value?

Comment: You can sidestep lhopitals by using series expansions for square root and log and multiplying them. Then showing the limit for each term. To use lhopitals, turn the expression into a fraction. I.e. generally keep the log in the numerator and put the other stuff in the denominator (with sign flip of exponents).

Comment: Camillus.Have a look at the appended version.Is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

1.)

Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ then $f(x,y)$ becomes $(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)r\ln r$ and recall that $\lim_{r\to 0}{r\ln r}=0$

2.)

Use the same polar substitution.

Answer (score 0):

For the second, fix $y\ne 0$ and allow $x\to 0.$ Then you have $$-\frac{y^3}{y^2}=-y\to 0$$ as $y\to 0.$