# Prove $\lim\limits _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}xy\ln(x^2+y^2)=0$ by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Prove $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}xy\ln(x^2+y^2)=0$$
I want to prove it by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ as the following:
Given $ε>0$, there exist $δ>0$ such that if 
$$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r<δ$$
then 
$$0<\lvert xy\ln(x^2+y^2)\rvert <\lvert r^2 \sin θ \cosθ \ln(r^2) \rvert<\lvert r^2 \ln r \rvert$$
In the last inequality, I don’t know how to proceed. Is it only possible to be solved by L’Hospital’s rule in the last inequality for $r^2 \ln r$? But I thought everything can be written in $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: You can replace $r=e^{-s}$ for $s\to+\infty$. Then $|r^2\ln(r)|=\frac{s}{e^{2s}}\leq \frac{s}{(1+s)^2}$ You can solve now $\frac{s}{(1+s)^2}<\epsilon$ to get an interval of the form $s>M$ in its set of solutions. This in turn will give you an interval $0<r<\delta$ such that $|r^2\ln(r)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213294/limits-of-functions-with-two-variables/3213308#3213308

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to relate the radius of the neighborhood $\delta$ around $0$ to $\epsilon$ such that the function is within the desired error bound for all points within the neighborhood. So it makes more sense to fix $\epsilon > 0$ and find $(x,y)$ of maximal distance from $0$ for which $|f(x,y) - 0| < \epsilon$. That is to say,
$$\begin{align*}
\epsilon 
&> \left|xy \log(x^2+y^2)\right| \\ 
&= \left|r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \log r^2\right| \\
&\ge 2\left|r^2 \log r\right| \\
&> r^2 \left|\log r\right|.
\end{align*}$$
Note that this bound need not be tight.  In the neighborhood of $0$, is there a function that is even smaller than $r^2 \left|\log r\right|$?  Of course:  when $0 < r < 1/e < 1$, we easily have $\left| \log r \right| = -\log r > 1$, so on this interval $r < \left| \log r \right|$, consequently $$\epsilon > r^2 \left| \log r \right| > r^3,$$ hence for all $0 < \delta < \min(\epsilon^{1/3}, e^{-1/3})$, we have $|f(x,y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} < \delta$, and this establishes the desired relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: The second line of your set of inequalities lines is $\left|r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \log r^2\right|$. However, note that $\sin \theta \cos \theta \log r^2 = (2\sin \theta \cos \theta) \log r = \sin(2\theta)\log r$. Since $\left| \sin(2\theta)\right| \le 1$, this means $\left|r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \log r^2\right| \le r^2\left|\log r\right|$, contradicting your next $2$ lines.